# Cannot access app.instance_path in Flask

Tags: python, flask, flask-wtforms

I am trying to implement a [file upload](https://flask-wtf.readthedocs.io/en/stable/form.html#module-flask_wtf.file) function in my Flask app, but then I try:

```
f.save(os.path.join(app.instance_path, 'imgs', filename))
```

within my class, I keep getting errors. The first time, I got:

```
NameError: name 'app' is not defined
```

Then I tried importing app with `import app` and got the following:

```
AttributeError: module 'app' has no attribute 'instance_path'
```

I am using [Flask-Foundation](https://jackstouffer.com/flask-foundation/) as a framework, and have a Flask application factory creating my app (using the name `app`). Using Flask version 0.12.2.

Should I specify the instance_path in my settings.py file? However, as the [documentation](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/config/#instance-folders) says:

> You can either explicitly provide the path of the instance folder when creating the Flask application or you can let Flask autodetect the instance folder.

So I figured I do not need to specify it, and something with my naming might be wrong.... any ideas?

Thanks!
Daniel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, fixed by correcting the import:

```
import appname.app
```

Then:

```
f.save(os.path.join(appname.app.instance_path, 'imgs', filename))
```

(of course `appname` should be whatever you app is named...)

Answer (score 0):

also try

```
from flask import current_app
print(current_app.instance_path)
print(current_app.root_path)
```

this more dynamic as folder may change on host, also if you have multiple blueprints so you always have current_app in flask